# Apache Log Parser to Block Certain IP's

Tags: bash, apache, shell

So, using the following I can get a list of IP address

```
cat access.* | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | awk '{print $1;}' | sort -n >> toblock.txt
```

How can I filter it to write out **only** the bots IPs?

Then I can pass it to:

```
for i in `cat block.txt`; do csf -d $i;done
```

So I can block them...

Comment: my attempt is to find the bots accessing it, and blocking them through csf

Comment: So how do you identify a bot ?

Comment: I would think via the user-agent in the log line for apache's access log...

Comment: For the purpose of this question, I am after the user-agent alone.

Comment: Check fail2ban. Here's an example setup to get you rolling this thing fast: http://rauxbenoit.tumblr.com/post/573694569/apache-security-apache-bot-filtering-with

Comment: @Marged.  Please... I did use the plural forms of the nouns, hoping that would imply an obviousness of "more than one"...

Answer (score 0):

Note - As described above, what you suggest will block ALL Traffic from the source IP; if that is your intention then that's fine - you might also consider using 'mod_security' (This post covers using: ~/.htaccess with mod_rewrite rules, firewall rules, and mod_security - [blocking the80 legs crawler](http://web-tech.ga-usa.com/2012/02/banning-bad-robots-crawlers/)) - with mod_security it is much easier to setup dynamic rules matching 'bots' and deny with one rule versus potentially thousands of firewall rules...

If you prefer the firewall approach, then perhaps better to:

- lookup the DNS information for the IP
- block the entire RANGE for the bot with one rule...

Back to your query, you need  to create a REGEX (regular expression) pattern for the 'bad bots', so something like:

```
BAD_BOTS="bad_bot1|very bad bot|super bad bot|etc bad bot patterns"
```

then (ignore case and search for these patterns)

```
egrep -i "${BAD_BOTS}" access.* | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq >> toblock.txt
```

I am not familiar with 'csf' so I cannot comment on that part of your question.

:)
Dale